# Не запускается php-файл в браузере

Tags: ajax, php

Запускаю php файл, и в браузере он думает и думает. Работаю в PHPstorm, server.php и js лежат в одной папке. Может, я неправильно обращаюсь к файлу server.php в AJAX?

`GET http://localhost:63342/server.php 404 (Not Found)` - это выдает в консоли.

```
    <?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, Accept');

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
{
    $body = file_get_contents('php://input');

    file_put_contents("users.json", $body);

    echo "OK";
}
else if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "GET")
{
    echo file_get_contents("users.json");
}
```

Comment: Консоль ругается на то, что файла, собственно, нету. Другой значит путь

Comment: > выдает в консоле

в консол**и**

PHPStorm всегда раздает контент внутри проекта, т.е. корень сервера не localhost:63342/, а localhost:63342/MyMegaProject/. При работе с файлом в правом верхнем углу должны появляться иконки браузеров, которые откроют этот файл в браузере по нажатию.

Comment: все равно не работает(

Comment: может проблема в php коде?
потому что даже отдельно server.php не загружаеться

Comment: @Серёжа Сухинин, по диагнозу "не работает" без подробностей очень сложно что-либо сказать.

Comment: @Etki,в файле server.php нажимаю на значок google chrome,он открывает пустую страницу и она грузиться бесконечно